# How does RegExp access the string it operates on?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering how accessing to strings is done. The String object exposes methods such as char(Code)At for public access, but doesn't use them itself as part of its other methods, for example indexOf, but instead accesses the string through an internal structure. However, when using a RegExp, I assume it can't use String's private properties, so it has to call the public API as any other class. I wrote a short test to see that, but it doesn't seem that's what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/n5pxe94L/

```
String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]=function*()
{
    console.log("My custom iterator!");
    yield "t";
};

const originalFunc=String.prototype.charCodeAt;
String.prototype.charCodeAt=function(index)
{
    console.log("Used!");
    return originalFunc.call(this,index);
}

new RegExp("a").test("Lalalala");
```

When I run this test, it doesn't print anything, which indicates the functions I overrode aren't used! So how does RegExp access the string it analyzes?

Comment: *“However, when using a RegExp, I assume it can't use String's private properties, so it has to call the public API as any other class.”* That’s not a correct assumption. You can’t change the string a primitive string represents – think about it like overriding an integer in other languages.

Comment: (You can’t even hide it from user code; `"hello".length === 5 && "hello"[0] === "h"` no matter how much arcane prep work is done.)

Comment: AFAIK, javascript constructs a new string object when you attempt to call a method on a string primative. That object has all the methods that you are overriding.  The RegExp test method is probably directly accessing the primative without constructing a string object.

Comment: It is highly probable that in all current implementations (and even all previous implementations) of javascript the `RegExp` object is accessing the underlying `char*` of the string because both `String` and `RegExp` is and were implemented in C/C++ (excluding of course Rhino which was written in Java - in which case it was probably Java's String class)

Answer (score 0):

It's all done in the JavaScript engine however that engine sees fit to do it. Each JavaScript implementation may take a different approach, but they all have direct, very low-level access to the string's content. For performance reasons I'd expect these access methods to be highly optimized and direct, not allowing for overrides like you've attempted here as that would slow things down in the 99.9999% of cases where no such override exists.

JavaScript is not stuck using functions exposed in the API, it may have many others that are hidden from developers and for internal use only.

If you're writing JavaScript code you're stuck using the features available to you. If you're writing a JavaScript runtime you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Most of this is shown by the phrase `[native code]` when you try to log built-in functions to the console.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Note that in most current implementations the interpreter will show `[native code]` for built-in functions even if those functions were implemented in javascript instead of C (simply a library implementation instead of low level code). I remember this used to work differently in the mid 2000s where you can sometimes log the code for built-in functions

Comment: Some javascript interpreters such as node.js allows you to write "javascript" libraries/modules in C/C++ instead of javascript. When you have C you obviously have access to the underlying `char*` for the region of RAM that is the string. Older browsers also allowed you to do this via plugins/extensions which was how Java applets and Flash was originally implemented however most browsers have either deprecated or completely disabled this in favor of pure-javascript extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I wanted to simply answer along the lines of `RegExp` accesses the underlying string structure in C but I got curious so started digging into the source code of various javascript engines.

All the javascript engines commonly in use (which are V8 for Chrome and node.js, Chakra for Edge and JavascriptCore for Safari) implement regexp processing in C++. I couldn't find the exact regexp processing functions in Chakra and JavascriptCore but I'm sure if I spend a few days reading the code I'll find it.

For Chakra you will see that most of the Regexp methods in C++ accept an argument called `input` which is defined as `Char*`. I'm not sure if `input` is the string or the regexp pattern but I'm guessing it's the string. But note that it is `Char` not `char` so it is probably a custom class in the project. You can start by looking at the Chakra RegexpRuntime implementation here: https://github.com/microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/master/lib/Parser/RegexRuntime.cpp

For JavascriptCore best I can tell is that they pass the C++ `JSString` object to the regexp function. This is as close as to actually using the actual `String` prototype in js but it probably has methods not available to js: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/RegExpObject.cpp

I got the furthest with V8 in the last 15 minutes. V8 passes a parameter called `subject` as the string to regexp functions. This is a `String` object which is then converted to `String::FlatContent`. Now what is `FlatContent`? It is an array-like object (see the `Vector` class) of either 8 bit or 16 bit values that you can access using the `[]` operator in C++. This allows them to loop through the string using regular array indexing. You can start by checking out `regexp.cc`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/regexp/regexp.cc

As you can see, none of them access strings via Javascript's String object as is. The closest that works kind of how you expected them to behave is Apple's JavascriptCore in Safari but even then it's not using merely APIs exposed via javascript.